# Word for somebody that is prejudiced against people who identify as non-binary?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, social-gender

What is the most specific way to describe somebody prejudiced against non-binary individuals?

For context on what I'm looking for:

- A person who hates somebody because of their race, is racist
- A person who hates somebody because they are transgender, is transphobic
- A person who hates somebody because they are homosexual, is homophobic
- A person who hates somebody because they are non-binary, is (?)

Comment: What on earth is a binary individual?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genderqueer - "non-binary, is a catch-all category for gender identities that are not exclusively masculine or feminine‍—‌identities which are outside the gender binary and cisnormativity"

Comment: I’m all at ones and zeros over this.

Comment: Does prejudice mean hatred? Or are you just looking for a meaningless perjorative? How about tricyclophobic? Then again …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically mean someone who is prejudiced against non-binary individuals but not against trans women or trans men? If your readers know the term "enby" for "non-binary", then you could try "enbyphobe".

This prejudice is a specific form of transphobia, in that non-binary people count as trans, because everyone was assigned either male or female at birth, so identifying as non-binary entails transitioning. Transitioning doesn't just cover transitioning from male to female or female to male -- it also covers non-binary, genderqueer, genderfluid, third gender etc..

Comment: Thanks very much. From your question; does that mean transphobia considered the catch-all, for transgender and non-binary; if so - please also include that, that's a perfectly valid answer too. Thanks very much for the "enbyphobe" answer too. The main reason for asking was having seen this behaviour, but not having any succinct way to describe it (and being wary of using the wrong term).

Comment: I classify enbyphobia as a specific form of transphobia because enby people count as trans, because everyone was assigned either male or female at birth, so identifying as enby entails transitioning. Transitioning doesn't just cover transitioning from male to female or female to male -- it also covers enby, genderqueer, genderfluid, third gender etc.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of thing I was after. Can you add that bit into the answer for completeness?

Comment: Downvoter, please could you explain? Have I misrepresented non-binary people?

Answer (score -1):

Homophobia is a old term now it’s called heterosexism.

Comment: This would benefit from more explanation and sources of usage from your research.

Comment: Google NGrams shows that *heterosexism* and *heterosexist* have always been much rarer than *homophobia* and *homophobic*. According to Google NGrams, the terms had a local peak around 2000, at which time the *homo-* words were the more used by a factor of about 4. Since about 2010, those have become even more frequently used, whereas the *hetero-* words have declined in BrE usage, and risen more slowly in AmE.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about a prejudice based on gender identity, rather than sexual orientation.